# Avoid s in footnote

Tags: acronyms

I use the `acronym` package for creating footnotes. Those I usually mark with `\ac{MyWord}` and if plural then `\acp{MyWord}`. To import the package, I use:

```
\usepackage[footnote, printonlyused]{acronym}
```

My problem is in the footnote when making use of `\acp`. It ads an "s" at the end of the sentence and I would like to avoid that.

**Example:**

```
\ac{HTML}
```

Creates in my case the footnote:
*Language used in the web.*

```
\acp{HTML}
```

creates in my case the footnote:
*Language used in the web.s*

How can I get rid of the "s" at the end of the footnote created by `\acp{HTML}`?

**Edit 1 - code example:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[footnote, printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}
    \section{Test Chapter}
        This is a Test for showing the error. No error with \ac{HTML} using ac, but an unwanted "s" is added with \acp{Action} when using acp.
        \bigskip
    \section*{Acronyms}
    \begin{acronym}[Action]
        \acro{HTML}{Language used in the web.}
        \acro{Action}{Used within the math function as a parameter.}
    \end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example, please?

Comment: I am very confused reading the question. An acronym is something like CD (compact disc). THe long form should not be a complete sentence. And why do you have a plural form of HTML?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I think, it should be more of a glossary, perhaps? But a plural of `HTML` seems weird indeed

Comment: HTML is just an example. I write in German where it makes sense to have an "s" for plural at the end of a word, but not within the footnote. I added an edit with a code example.

Comment: In my point of view, it would be much better to have a real example, even if it is in german. Quite a few of LaTeX users here are germans.

Comment: Have you considered using `\newacroplural{acronym}[short plural]{long plural}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see the extra `s` :-p But i think using `acronym` is the wrong approach here and `glossaries` should be used.

Comment: Tried myself with `glossaries` using the examples of https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries. Though I can't get them running properly. No footnotes and no listing appears. I use `xetex` as a compiler.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've looked at the wrong place, actually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to redefine the plural form with`\acrodefplural`

```
\begin{acronym}[Action]
    \acro{HTML}{Hyper Text Markup Language}
    \acrodefplural{HTML}[HTML]{Hyper Text Markup Languages}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: Totally confused myself. But this works. Though you need to build it at least twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't get it running with `\newacroplural`, but I solved it using `\acrodefplural{Action}[Actions]{Action is used within the math function as a parameter.}` in the same way as in your example. It works now even though I have redundant double text. Better dirty than not at all.

Comment: so I change it to `acrodefplural`. But I'm not sure, if `acronym` is the right package. Wouldn't `glossaries` be better?

Comment: Maybe `glossaries` is the better package, but I couldn't get it working using `xetex`. For now this workaround will have to do. I might start a new post for `glossaries`.

Comment: @Socrates: Do you have `makeglossaries` as well?